# Plot correlation between random intercept and slope glmmTMB?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glmmtmb

I am after some advice regarding how to plot the correlation between a random intercept and slope from a mixed model in `glmmTBM`?

Below is a reproducible example.

```
library(dplyr); library(glmmTMB)

# Create grouping variable
iris$group <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width <= 2.8, 1, ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width > 2.8 & iris$Sepal.Width < 3.5, 2, 3))

# Factorise grouping variable
iris$group <- factor(iris$group)

# Build model with random intercept and slope
i1 <- glmmTMB(Petal.Width ~ 
+                         Sepal.Length + (Sepal.Length | group), 
+                     data = iris, family = gaussian)

# Summarise i1
summary(i1)

Family: gaussian  ( identity )
Formula:          Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + (Sepal.Length | group)
Data: iris

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   146.2    164.2    -67.1    134.2      144 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr  
 group    (Intercept)  1.42773  1.1949         
          Sepal.Length 0.02903  0.1704   -0.98 
 Residual              0.12987  0.3604         
Number of obs: 150, groups:  group, 3

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2): 0.13 

Conditional model:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -2.7186     0.7340  -3.704 0.000213 ***
Sepal.Length   0.6606     0.1076   6.141 8.19e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The summary of the model that I have built (note that this is a meaningless model) shows that there is a negative correlation (-0.98) between the random intercept and random slope in our model. I.e when `iris$group` increases `iris$Sepal.Length` decreases.

My question is how would I graphically represent this correlation between the intercept and slope? Can this correlation be plotted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, you could visually represent the groups and their slopes.

I chose to use ggeffects::ggpredict() to get the marginal means.

```
ggeffects::ggpredict(i1, terms = c("Sepal.Length","group"), type = "re") %>% plot()
```

This gives a visual representation of the -0.98 correlation of group & Sepal Length, where the higher the value, the less steep the slope.

[image]